# if condition not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery function and a javascript function. On clicking a link I want to run the jquery function first and if returns true then it should call the javascript function.

html file

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="return $('#a').click() ? addInput(): true" >
```

Jquery function

```
$(function () {

    $('a').click(function () {
        var clickCount = jQuery.data(this, 'clickCount');
        if (!clickCount) {
            clickCount = 0
        }
        clickCount++;
        jQuery.data(this, 'clickCount', clickCount);
        alert(clickCount);
        if (clickCount < 4) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Javascript function

```
<script>
#.. do something
</script>
```

my problem is that the *if* condition in the jquery is not functioning. But the javascript function is called and javascript function is working fine.

Am i doing it wrong?

How can i do it

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.click()` (with no arguments) triggers the event handler, but it returns the jQuery object you called it on. The return value from the handler function is used by jQuery to decide whether to stop event propagation and prevent default behaviour. (By the way "jQuery functions" _are_ JavaScript functions. jQuery isn't a separate language.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't call `addInput()` from the click event handler. Like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

    $('a').click(function()
    {
        var clickCount = jQuery.data( this, 'clickCount');                        
        if (!clickCount)
        {
            clickCount  = 0
        }        
    clickCount++;       
    jQuery.data( this, 'clickCount',clickCount);
    alert(clickCount);
    if(clickCount<4)
    {
        return addInput();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

html file

```
<a href="javascript:void()" >
```

Jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('a').click(function(event)
        {
            var clickCount = jQuery.data( this, 'clickCount');                        
            if (!clickCount)
            {
                clickCount  = 0
            }        
        clickCount++;       
        jQuery.data( this, 'clickCount',clickCount);

        if(clickCount<4)
        {
            //Do  something
        }
        else
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why no like this?

HTML:

```
<a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickCount = jQuery.data( this, 'clickCount');                        
        if (!clickCount) {
            clickCount  = 0
        }        
        clickCount++;       
        jQuery.data( this, 'clickCount',clickCount);
        alert(clickCount);
        if(clickCount<4) {
            addInput();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need not put `onclick="return $('#a').click() ? addInput(): true"` in anchor tag. Because if you mention `$('a').click(function(){}` in jQuery then it means that whenever you click on link  this function will be called. So instead of returning `true/false` from jQuery function you can directly call `addInput()` from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a ; after `clickCount  = 0`

Comment: How does this solve the problem? That missing semicolon isn't actually a syntax error and that line will work with or without it...